# ¿Cómo redireccionar a una vista Asp.Net Mvc enviando parámetros?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Ejecuto una  función con Ajax  y obtengo unos parámetros…

¿Cómo puedo hacer para redireccionar a una vista pasándole el (data) que obtengo como resultado de esta llamada?

Código C#:

```
public ActionResult Redirecto(string _ref)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ref))
        {
            Parameters todosLosParametros = GetParameters(id);
            return Json(todosLosParametros);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Código JavaScript:

```
function Redirecto() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Redirecto",
        data: { _ref: 'az1245'},
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
           //AQUI CODIGO PARA ABRIR LA VISTA PASANDOLE PARAMETROS
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log('RedirecTo');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mientras tu segundo Action sea de tipo **Get** y tenga parámetros de **tipo primitivo** lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

Supongamos que este es el Action de tu segundo View:

```
public ActionResult OtroAction(int valor, string cadena)
{
    //El resto de tu código
}
```

Entonces en tu petición AJAX podrías hacer esto:

```
success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
       
        var $valor = data.ValorNumerico;
        var $cadena = data.ValorCadena;
        window.location = "/NombreControlador/OtroAction?valor=" + $valor + "&cadena=" + $cadena;
    },
```

En caso de que tu Action sea de tipo **POST** o tenga un parámetro de tipo **objeto/modelo**, has considerado utilizar PartialViews?